# Buxus sempervirens - Deformed leaves

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, diseases, leaves, plant-care

Can anyone help me? Suddenly my Buxus sempervirens appeared with the new shoots with deformed leaves. I'm in zone 9. It has not been cold though, and yes, it's a lot humidity every night.

[image][image]